# Looking for a word inot a text excluding a caracter

Tags: file, sed, txt

I've a database, where I am looking for a specific sentence.... BUT I need to exclude `/`

I explain :

Into the wordpress (`http://www.example.com`) , I can see a wrong link `http://www.example.comfoo` instead of `http://www.example.com/foo`

So, how can I use sed to detect the words `example.com` **and not** `example.com/`  (I need to exclude the `/`)
This is probably this missing "/"; which cause the trouble
Thanks and regards

Never succeed.. I tried different possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression that matches `example.com` followed by either the end of the line `$` or a character that isn't `/`:

```
grep -E 'example\.com($|[^/])'
```

If you can use PCRE, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
grep -P 'example\.com(?!/)'
```